# Western isekai novel; boy and girl receive fantastic items for a legend-like quest

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, isekai

I just started wondering about the name of a novel I read in elementary school, in Finland in the 90s. It might have been the first fantasy novel I ever read, so my recollection of the elements of the story is fairly hazy.

The story starts when a boy and a girl are separately isekai'd. They end up going on a quest and meeting. I think they received a few fantastic items to help. I remember the girl was given a handkerchief with a knot in each corner, and each corner had a wind in it. I think she got it from a witch.

She ended up pulling all the knots open at once to start a storm, to get out of a situation. I think the storm carried her and the boy away from wherever they were.

One of the places they passed by on their quest was a room with two doors. Behind each door was one of the main character's dream rooms. I don't remember anything about the actual contents of the rooms. The boy had been raised in small studio flats by a single mom, so he wanted a room of his own. Therefore, one of the properties of the room was that nobody could enter the room unless the boy hit the door with a knife and told it to open for that person. Trying to enter the room would otherwise return a person to the central room. The girl's room seemed mostly mundane other than being exactly the room she always wanted to have.

It was a full novel, but it was fairly thin, especially for a fantasy novel. It was from an elementary school library, and I think the cover might have looked like it was from an assortment of novels intended for an elementary school library.

Comment: Hmm... the handkerchief with the winds sounds familiar, but that might be because it was a common charm sold in the real world to sailors, and therefore cropped up in fiction (often with there being three knots, with instructions on when to do the first and second one, with disaster happening after someone undoes the third knot, and summons a storm).